# In Visual Studio Code, how does one clear multi-line cursors using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, multipleselection

In Visual Studio code, you can use a keyboard shortcut to create multiple cursors above and below the current line, allowing to edit on multiple spots in the code. See also the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor)

However, once you have done your multiline edits, how does one clear the multiple cursors, using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Esc?..................

Comment: @Alex Nope. Or nope when you have it bound to Intellisense autocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keybindings.json` (instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> you can use your keybinding):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+;",
    "command": "removeSecondaryCursors",
    "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections && editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "-removeSecondaryCursors",
    "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections && editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo, in the second block, it should be "removeSecondayrCursors", not with the dash.

Btw, it works :D Thanks!

Comment: Dash stands for [removing keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you're asking how to exit multiline edit mode? I believe you simply press <kbd>esc</kbd>